# How can I mirror my GitLab commits to GitHub for a more active profile?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm currently employed at a company that uses GitLab for version control and repository management. However, many job applications require a GitHub profile as part of their criteria, and my primary platform for development work is GitLab. Consequently, my GitHub profile appears inactive and devoid of contributions.

Is there a way for me to automatically mirror or sync my GitLab commits to GitHub to bolster my profile with the work I'm actively doing on GitLab?

Comment: If your employer discovers you've mirrored company property to another source control repository, you will be fired and sued for legal damages and lost revenue.

Answer (score 2):

This is a **terrible** idea. Please do not do it. Who'd trust an engineer who violated confidentiality just for the green squares?

"My current employer uses GitLab" should be *plenty* of explanation why your GitHub profile doesn't have a lot of green squares. (In this case, it's also true, but feel free to substitute "private Git server" or another hosting provider as appropriate.) Any employer who doesn't accept that explanation is not worth the trouble.